# testing PayPal IPN using beyondcode/expose to use a designated port - how to

Tags: php, laravel, docker, paypal-ipn, laravel-sail

I am using docker, and attempting to

```
sail share
```

so i can get a tunnel to my local computer to test PayPal IPN.  When i Share to get that tunnel i get

```
sail share
Thank you for using expose.
Local-URL:      host.docker.internal:80
Dashboard-URL:      http://127.0.0.1:4040
Expose-URL:     http://eavglxsmrk.laravel-sail.site:8080
```

When I point PayPal's ipn message to the exposed-url, it does not work because IPN will only send messages to the convential internet ports 80 or 443.

So I purchased the Expose Pro package so I could create a subdomain with no port, so I guees it would use port 80.  But when I try to run the expose to the domain that has not port designated I get a whopping mouthfull of Deprecateed error.  here is a small sample (actually they will be at the end.

I tried running expose both inside the docker / sail shell, and out side of it.    Sail Share still works, but it produces the :8080 port reference, which IPN does not like.

If I try

```
sail expose token [token goes here]
```

I get a less ominous error page.

```
No such command: expose

Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services
  config             Validate and view the Compose file
  create             Create services
  down               Stop and remove resources
  events             Receive real time events from containers
  exec               Execute a command in a running container
  help               Get help on a command
  images             List images
  kill               Kill containers
  logs               View output from containers
  pause              Pause services
  port               Print the public port for a port binding
  ps                 List containers
  pull               Pull service images
  push               Push service images
  restart            Restart services
  rm                 Remove stopped containers
  run                Run a one-off command
  scale              Set number of containers for a service
  start              Start services
  stop               Stop services
  top                Display the running processes
  unpause            Unpause services
  up                 Create and start containers
  version            Show version information and quit

Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose`
```

My objective is to get rid of the port reference so IPN can send its message to my local computer.

any hints out there?

Thank you.

below is a sample of the errors I get when I try to run expose in the Mac environment, outside the docker shell.  this is the version i have of php running in the Mac OS:

```
 php --version
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2022 04:47:46) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

This is the version of php i have withing the docker shell:

```
sail php --version
PHP 8.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:14:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

and below is a sample of the long deprecated warning i get when i try to expose my token in the mac os, outside of the docker shell.  It looks like the expose outside is conflicting with the expose that is inside the docker shell:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of HumbugBox3122\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 12

Deprecated: Return type of HumbugBox3122\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 12
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of HumbugBox3122\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 16

Deprecated: Return type of HumbugBox3122\KevinGH\RequirementChecker\RequirementCollection::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/src/RequirementCollection.php on line 16
PHP Deprecated:  getopt(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($short_options) of type string is deprecated in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/expose on line 22

Deprecated: getopt(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($short_options) of type string is deprecated in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/expose on line 22
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1355

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1355
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1366

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1366
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1378

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1378
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1391

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1391
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of PhpOption\Some::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/Some.php on line 152

Deprecated: Return type of PhpOption\Some::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/Some.php on line 152
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of PhpOption\None::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/None.php on line 118

Deprecated: Return type of PhpOption\None::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/None.php on line 118
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 141

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 141
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 152

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 152
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 164

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 164
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 175

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 175
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 608

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 608
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 690

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 690
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FileTypeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php on line 42

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FileTypeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php on line 42
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren(): RecursiveDirectoryIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 85

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren(): RecursiveDirectoryIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 85
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 113

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 113
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::current() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::current(): SplFileInfo|FilesystemIterator|string, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 61

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::current() should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::current(): SplFileInfo|FilesystemIterator|string, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 61
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php on line 55

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php on line 55
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::hasChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::hasChildren(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php on line 74

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::hasChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::hasChildren(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php on line 74
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php on line 79

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php on line 79
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilenameFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilenameFilterIterator.php on line 28

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilenameFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilenameFilterIterator.php on line 28
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php on line 27

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php on line 27
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php:1443
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'phar:///Users/r...', 1443)
#1 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('phar:///Users/r...')
#2 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('phar:///Users/r...')
#3 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): collect(Array)
#5 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
#6 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#7 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(71): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(LaravelZero\Framework\Application))
#8 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(243): LaravelZero\Framework\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(LaravelZero\Framework\Application))
#9 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#10 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Kernel.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#11 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Kernel.php(102): LaravelZero\Framework\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Kernel.php(89): LaravelZero\Framework\Kernel->ensureDefaultCommand(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
#13 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/expose(46): LaravelZero\Framework\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose(14): require('phar:///Users/r...')
#15 {main} in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php on line 13
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php:1443
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'phar:///Users/r...', 1443)
#1 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('phar:///Users/r...')
#2 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/.box/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('phar:///Users/r...')
#3 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/illuminate/collections/helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): collect(Array)
#5 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
#6 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#7 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(71): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(LaravelZero\Framework\Application))
#8 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(243): LaravelZero\Framework\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(LaravelZero\Framework\Application))
#9 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/foundation/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#10 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Kernel.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#11 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Kernel.php(102): LaravelZero\Framework\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 phar:///Users/robertbryandavis/.composer/vendor/beyondcode/expose/builds/expose/vendor/laravel-zero/framework/src/Kernel.php(89): LaravelZero\Framework\Kernel->ensureDefaultCommand(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
```

Comment: Why are you testing IPN? It's 20 years old, there's no reason to be using IPN today. It is for old integrations only.

Comment: 20 yrs old is old in the computer age, I do admit.  Not to use excuses, but I use it because I understand it more than I do webhooks, so perhaps I am lazy, but I am also 60 and tend to want to do things faster so I can do other things, so I revert to the old, as I, I suppose, am old as I am thrice the age of IPN.  So, I guess I am just an old integration kind of guy.  Perhaps I am just stupid.  Ignorant.  Pitiful. Crazy. An Idiot People Nincompoop.  But perhaps this moniker of mine, IPN is better than yours? CHNM - Cotton headed ninny muggins

Answer (score 0):

well, it turns out that Sail uses a dedicated network with expose, so you cannot use the Expose Pro within a Sail/Docker container.  Additionally, Expose needed to issue an update in order for it to work with php 8.1.  They issued the update today.  And Now I am able to expose my local host to a chosen domain name at sharedwithexpose.com.  And, Expose exposes a secure port 443 so Paypal will be able to  communicate with it.

So consider this issue closed i suppose.